# Xamarin.Forms+PRISM How to get the viewmodel instance related to a specific view?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to initialize an instance of viewmodel after the navigation is completed.

Why? because I want to retrieve some data from webservice into the view.

I have something like this:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://myapp.com/MainNavigationPage/DashboardPage?initialized=true"
                                                             , UriKind.Absolute)
                                                    , useModalNavigation: false);
```

So my question is:

Is there any way to get the created instance of viewmodel for that specific view?

I want to do something like what Stephen Cleary mentions in his post:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

```
var context = (Instance of viewModel for my view);
await context.InitializeAsync();
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the INavigationAware interface and respond to the OnNavigatingTo/OnNavigatedTo methods to load your data.  Loading async data in a ctor is not recommended.  The OnNavigatingTo method is a new method available in the current 6.3 preview.

Another option would be to override the ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory method and call your async initialization method when the VM is first created. You can use the current code as a guideline:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms/PrismApplication.cs#L25

You could also try using the Container.RegisterInstance method to provide a preconfigured VM to the view.

Comment: Well, I was trying to achieve this using OnNavigatingTo but when the InitiaizeAsync is called, the UI is blocked until the execution of this functions is finished.
Now I've tried with the ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory and the result is the same, the method is called correctly but I don't know how to execute without block the UI.

I don't have that problem if I use this:
    var context = (Instance of viewModel for my view);
    await context.InitializeAsync();

but obviously, is not the better way.

Comment: Finallly I think I found which was the problem. 
I was using absolute uri between each page, so in that inteval, the only thing i saw was a blank page for a 2~3 seconds.
After I used relative URI, half problem was solved.
The other half, was solved putting the InitializeAsync function on "OnNavigatedTo" method and calling the loading indicator on Viewmodel's constructor.

thanks for the help.